# Adding Span before specific string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string

Is it possible to add a HTML element before a specific string using jQuery? For example, if I have:

```
<h4>Men's Basketball vs. Georgetown</h4>
```

And I would like to make it:

```
<h4>Men's Basketball <span class="team">vs. Georgetown</span></h4>
```

Can I do that with jQuery? I have tried to use a variety of options (:contains, prepend(), html(), pop(), etc. But none of them seem to work exactly right.

Comment: Is there always going to be a `vs.` followed by a team name, then the end of the h4 tag?

Comment: Yes, the format will always be the same (vs. followed by a team name and the closing </h4>), but the team name after vs. will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/je9Aa/)***

Assuming that for every `h4` you would like the `vs.` *and* what follows wrapped in a span, then you should iterate through each one, determine the location of `vs.` in the string and then wrap it in a span.

html: `<h4>Men's Basketball vs. Georgetown</h4>`

css: `.team{ color: red; }`

js:

```
$("h4").each(function(){
 var v = 'vs.',t = $(this), prefix, suffix;
 if(t.text().indexOf(v) > -1 ){
  prefix = t.text().substr(0,t.text().indexOf(v));
  prefix += "<span class='team'>";
  suffix = t.text().substr(t.text().indexOf(v));   
  suffix += "</span>";
  t.html(prefix+suffix);
 }
});
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I'm sure the other options would work as well, but there are multiple instances, so this one seemed to work best. Thanks @Travis J!

Comment: When I try to replicate your answer I get a console error of "this.innerText is undefined"

Comment: @Chris - I made an edit to the answer which uses jQuery's `.text()` method. This should be more cross browser compliant, I believe that innerText was not supported before ie8. Supporting lower versions of ie can definitely be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

```
var h4 = $('h4');
var str = 'vs. Georgetown';
h4.html(h4.text().replace(str, '<span class="team">'+str+'</span>'));
```

Supposing you want to wrap `vs` and the end of the text in all `h4` elements, then you might do

```
$('h4').each(function(){
   var bip = $(this).text().split(/(?<vs)/);      
   if (!bip.length) return;
   $(this).html(bip[0]+'<span class="team">'+bip[1]+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: The "Georgetown" will be dynamic with different teams though.

Answer (score 0):

I would give the h4 an id if I were you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('h4').html().split('vs.');

    $('h4').html(function(){
        return text[0] + '<span class="team"> vs. '+ text[1] +'</span>';
    });
});
```

Or if you have an Id. Lets say Id1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('#Id1').html().split('vs.');

    $('#Id1').html(function(){
        return text[0] + '<span class="team"> vs. '+ text[1] +'</span>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do...

```
var str = $('h4').split('vs.'); // team name

$('h4').html(function(){
    return str[0] + 'vs. <span class="team"> '+ str[1] +'</span>';
});
```

This seems a bit more of a dynamic solution than the previous answer.

[Here's your working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aQpN/)

Comment: You're setting the same html in all h4 elements.

Comment: @dystroy I see nothing indicating in OP's question that there is more than one occurence, or that it'll be an issue. If it is, they can simply add a unique id or class and target it.