# How to insert tag before a string in html using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am finding all the text in the html document and I want to add span tag that holds some information about each text like below

```
def recursiveChildren(x):
    if "childGenerator" in dir(x):
      for child in x.childGenerator():

          recursiveChildren(child)
    else:

      if not x.isspace():

          content = x.string
          new_tag = soup.new_tag("span")
          content.insert_before(new_tag)
if __name__ == "__main__":

with open("path to html",'r') as file:
      soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
for child in soup.body.childGenerator():
   recursiveChildren(child)
```

I am getting error as string object has no attribute insert before. How can I insert tag before string. I also tried getting the parent tag of the string and add add span tag before parent tag contents but it creates a problem if there are nested tags as I want a span tag before each and every independent string. Is it Possible? something like below but in Python [Insert span tag before # content text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270726/insert-span-tag-before-content-text)

[Adding Span before specific string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861916/adding-span-before-specific-string-with-jquery)

Example Html:

```
<p class=MsoNormal >This is first string <b> Second String </b> , </span><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

I want the output like

```
<p class=MsoNormal >**<span>**This is first string</span> <b>**<span>** Second String </span></b>**<span>** , </span><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content = x.string` then `content.insert_before(new_tag)` is your problem.

```
if not x.isspace():
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("span")
    x.insert_before(new_tag)
```

---

`soup.body.childGenerator()` returns a list of `bs4.element`. These are able to perform complex operations, like the insert you are trying to do.

This is what your function `recursiveChildren` got as argument `x`. So `x` is able to `insert_before`.

But when doing `content = x.string` you are storing within `content` a simple HTML string (type of `str` in python). Obviously string does not support `insert_before` - You have to do this on `x`.

---

Btw, you should give a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - `recursiveChildren` would be better named `recursive_children` and `x` is a bad variable name, you should name it `element` or something like that.

*[Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)*